# Formatting text in a tkinter messagebox in two columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Normally I format text in a console with fixed-length characters.
Now I want to do something similar in a tkinter messagebox, but this messes up the indentation.
For example this

```
from tkinter import messagebox

    info = {'Everything': 'first one', 'should be': 'second one', 'evenly outlined': 'another one', 'ms are really long':'previous to the last', 'mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm': "you see?"}
    infostring = (f"{k: <20}:{v}" for k, v in info.items())
    messagebox.askokcancel(
        title="outlining",
        icon=messagebox.QUESTION,
        message=("Is this your outlined well?\n\n" + "\n".join(infostring)),
    )
```

results in

[image]

whereas in a console it would be:

```
Everything          :first one
should be           :second one
evenly outlined     :another one
ms are really long  :previous to the last
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm     :you see?
```

And this is how I want it in the messagebox.

Comment: I think it is because of the font, in consoles the font is monospaced fonts(having equal width) but in tkinter the default font does not seem to be monospaced. Eg: Monospaced O and I would take same space, but normal fonts, O will take more space than I and this might be your issue.

Comment: The font of the messagebox is not fixed, so you can't indent. You could try using tabulators, but that may look even worse in the end.
Either set the font of the messagebox (e.g.: `font = ('Courier',12)`) or use a custom window with a text widget in it. There, you can set the font to a fixed space font (e.g. "Courier" or "fixedsys") and you will get a nicely formated table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible using the normal `MessageBox` as a result of OS level restrictions. However, you can do it in a label by setting `justify` to `tkinter.LEFT`.

Here's some example code:

```py
import tkinter
msg = """Everything          :first one
should be           :second one
evenly outlined     :another one
ms are really long  :previous to the last
mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm     :you see?"""
r = tkinter.Tk()

label1 = tkinter.Label(r, text=msg, font=("Consolas", 12), justify=tkinter.LEFT)
label1.place(x=0,y=0)
r.mainloop()
```

Which outputs this:

[image: Message Box]

I apreciate this isn't an exact answer, and I'm not super well versed with Tkinter, but hopefully this will provide some help. Good Luck!

**Edit:**

I also used a monospace font, which will most likely be required to ensure the text is always a consistent width.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [`simpledialog`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dialog.html#tkinter-dialogs) module and build one yourself.

```py
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import simpledialog

class Dialog(simpledialog.Dialog):
    def __init__(self,master,title=None):
        root.bell()
        simpledialog.Dialog.__init__(self,master,title)

    def body(self,frame):
        icon_label=Label(frame,image='::tk::icons::question')
        icon_label.pack(side='left',anchor='n',padx=(0,10))
        label=Label(frame,text="Is this your outlined well?\n\n" + "\n".join(infostring),
            justify='left',font='Consolas 11')
        label.pack(side='right')
        return label

def dialog():
    Dialog(root,title='outlining')

root=Tk()

info = {'Everything': 'first one', 'should be': 'second one', 'evenly outlined': 'another one',
    'ms are really long':'previous to the last', 'mmmmmmmmmmmmmmm': "you see?"}
infostring = (f"{k: <20}:{v}" for k, v in info.items())

button=Button(root,text='Dialog',command=dialog)
button.pack(padx=100,pady=100)

root.mainloop()
```

You can also make the following changes to the `Dialog` class to make it look closer to the native.

```py
def body(self,frame):
    frame.config(bg='white')
    frame.master.config(bg=frame['bg'])
    icon_label=Label(frame,image='::tk::icons::question',bg=frame['bg'])
    icon_label.pack(side='left',anchor='n',padx=(0,10))
    label=Label(frame,text="Is this your outlined well?\n\n" + "\n".join(infostring),
        justify='left',font='Consolas 11',bg=frame['bg'])
    label.pack(side='right')
    return label

def buttonbox(self):

    box = Frame(self)

    w = ttk.Button(box, text="Cancel", width=10, command=self.cancel)
    w.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)
    w = ttk.Button(box, text="OK", width=10, command=self.ok, default=ACTIVE)
    w.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=5, pady=5)

    self.bind("<Return>", self.ok)
    self.bind("<Escape>", self.cancel)

    box.pack(fill='x')
```